# Using script tool input as variable in Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

I have made three different script tools to run in a module that is going to clean multiple sets of data as I get them.

```
import arcpy
fc = "C:\Users\CartoFront\Desktop\Chicago Update\Chicago Update.gdb\ChiMetroJoin12012016practice"
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdHouseNbr", "sthsnum", "sthsnum")
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdDirectionLeft", "stdir", "stdir")
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdStreet", "ststname", "ststname")
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdMode", "stsuffix", "stsuffix")
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdUnitType", "stunitprfx", "stunitprfx")
arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, "SitusStdUnitNbr", "stunitnum", "stunitnum")
```

I have previously just been editing the fc every time I run the script for the necessary input. However, I find this very counter-intuitive because I enter the same file input into my script tool every time I run it. 
Is there any way that I am able to set my inital fc variable to the input that I am entering into my script tool?

Comment: My apologies, just made the edit to change that. I have read through both of those Esri Help desk pages prior to asking, maybe I am just looking over the answer that is there. Just boggled down with the codes they provide for examples. I cant seem to see a way to set my initial code variable to the input in that example, is it just convoluted? Do you have any input on where I could look within that code? Sorry!

Comment: I am running it as an actual script tool from a custom ArcGIS toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a feature class or feature layer [parameter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf) in the script tool properties (right click the tool in your custom toolbox). Then use `fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` in your script.

See [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) and [Accessing parameters in a script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/accessing-parameters-in-a-script-tool.htm) for more details.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it.